# Mocking free function

Tags: c++, unit-testing, tdd, googlemock

I am stuck in a problem and can't seem to find the solution.

I am using VS2005 SP1 for compiling the code.

I have a global function:

```
A* foo();
```

I have a mock class

```
class MockA : public A {
public:
    MOCK_METHOD0 (bar, bool());
    ...
};
```

In the sources, it is accessed like this: `foo()->bar()`. I cannot find a way to mock this behavior. And I cannot change the sources, so the solution in google mock cook book is out of question.

Any help or pointers in the right direction will be highly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No it's not possible, without changing the sources, or bringing your own version of `foo()` that is linked with the executable code.

---

From [GoogleMock's FAQ](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/main/docs/gmock_faq.md#my-code-calls-a-staticglobal-function-can-i-mock-it) it says

> ### My code calls a static/global function. Can I mock it?
>
> You can, but you need to make some changes.
>
> In general, if you find yourself needing to mock a static function, it's a sign that your modules are too tightly coupled (and less flexible, less reusable, less testable, etc). You are probably better off defining a small interface and call the function through that interface, which then can be easily mocked. It's a bit of work initially, but usually pays for itself quickly.
>
> This Google Testing Blog [post](http://googletesting.blogspot.com/2008/06/defeat-static-cling.html) says it excellently. Check it out.

Also from the [Cookbook](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/main/docs/gmock_cook_book.md#mocking-free-functions)

> #### Mocking Free Functions
>
> It's possible to use Google Mock to mock a free function (i.e. a C-style function or a static method). You just need to rewrite your code to use an interface (abstract class).
>
> Instead of calling a free function (say, OpenFile) directly, introduce an interface for it and have a concrete subclass that calls the free function:
>
> ```
> class FileInterface {
> ```

```
 public:
  ...
  virtual bool Open(const char* path, const char* mode) = 0;
};
```

> ```
> class File : public FileInterface {
> ```

```
 public:
  ...
  virtual bool Open(const char* path, const char* mode) {
    return OpenFile(path, mode);
  }
};
```

> Your code should talk to FileInterface to open a file. Now it's easy to mock out the function.
>
> This may seem much hassle, but in practice you often have multiple related functions that you can put in the same interface, so the per-function syntactic overhead will be much lower.
>
> If you are concerned about the performance overhead incurred by virtual functions, and profiling confirms your concern, you can combine this with the recipe for mocking non-virtual methods.

---

As you mentioned in your comment that you actually provide your own version of `foo()`, you can easily solve this having a global instance of another mock class:

```
struct IFoo {
    virtual A* foo() = 0;
    virtual ~IFoo() {}
};

struct FooMock : public IFoo {
     FooMock() {}
     virtual ~FooMock() {}
     MOCK_METHOD0(foo, A*());
};

FooMock fooMock;

// Your foo() implementation
A* foo() {
    return fooMock.foo();
}

TEST(...) {
    EXPECT_CALL(fooMock,foo())
        .Times(1)
        .WillOnceReturn(new MockA());
    // ...
}
```

Don't forget to clear all call expectations, after each test case run.

Comment: Quoting from the question: "the solution in google mock cook book is out of question"

Comment: @leemes Then the answer is No.

Comment: I have my own version of foo(), and it returns a pointer to A. But when I try to set Expectations on it, i get the error that bar() is not a member. Like,

MockA *mocked_A;
A* foo() {
mocked_A = new A();
return mocked_A;
}

And i set the expectations like this:

EXPECT_CALL (mocked_A, bar());

but i get the error i mentioned earlier. Is there anything I can do to make it work ?

Comment: Actually, I was just given the header file, and the lib which  I link to. So, I do not link to the lib while unit testing and use my own foo() implementation.

Comment: @MuhammadHassan Well, if you have your own version of `foo()`, then you could create another mock class with a non static function and the same signature, create a global instance of that one and call it from `foo()`. Such you can set call expectations for the global instance of that mock.

Comment: @MuhammadHassan I've added a short sample, what it should look like.

Comment: @ πάντα ῥεῖ : Thanks a lot. It worked :) , I edited just one thing in your code, the return keyword.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ: I got stuck into another problem using the above solution;
Memory leaks. When my tests exit, it gives the error that the object should be deleted but is not. I changed the global obj to pointer, and deleted it at the end of test. Still getting errors. Any pointers ?

Comment: @MuhammadHassan Probably just having a `.WillOnceReturn(new MockA());` was too simplified. Do the `new MockA()` outside, and `delete` it before the testcase ends.

Comment: @ πάντα ῥεῖ: I didn't do it like that, I created a NiceMock <MockA> mockObj;  for MockA, and then returned that mock obj like .WillOnce(Return(&mockObj)). I will try your method too. Thanks.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ I still get memory leaks with the method. And I read somewhere that we cannot have global variables in gmock. So, how do I counter this problem?

Comment: @MuhammadHassan Sorry, I didn't realize it was you, when I duped your last question. Please ask it again, may be someone else can help you with this problem.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ haha. no problem :) I will ask again, i just deleted it, will undelete it  but if you find a way to fix memory leaks, please let me know. :) Also, can you unmark it as duplicate ? Thanks.

Comment: @MuhammadHassan You should be able to see your deleted question. Just go there, click edit and copy all the text for a new question.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ Yep, I undeleted it. Thanks. So, is it possible to unmark it as duplicate ?

Comment: @MuhammadHassan Yes I'll do.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ someone should add an answer with that solution.

Comment: @Adrian What do you mean? What's actually unclear here? Feel free to provide another answer _with that solution_.

Answer (score 5):

There are 2 options:

If you insist on using gmock, there's an "extension" for global mocking from apriorit: https://github.com/apriorit/gmock-global

It's rather limited, though - or at least I couldn't figure out in 5 minutes how to have side effects on a mocked call.

If you're willing to switch from gmock, then hippomocks has a very neat way of doing what you want.

Here's an example for mocking fopen, fclose and fgets for testing a member function which reads from a file using cstdio (streams are very inefficient):

```
TEST_CASE("Multi entry") {
    std::vector<std::string> files{"Hello.mp3", "World.mp3"};
    size_t entry_idx = 0;
    MockRepository mocks;
    mocks.OnCallFunc(fopen).Return(reinterpret_cast<FILE *>(1));
    mocks.OnCallFunc(fgets).Do(
        [&](char * buf, int n, FILE * f)->char *{ 
            if (entry_idx < files.size())
            {
                strcpy(buf, files[entry_idx++].c_str());
                return buf;
            }
            else
                return 0;
            }
        );
    mocks.OnCallFunc(fclose).Return(0);

    FileExplorer file_explorer;
    for (const auto &entry: files)
        REQUIRE_THAT(file_explorer.next_file_name(), Equals(entry.c_str()));
    REQUIRE_THAT(file_explorer.next_file_name(), Equals(""));
}
```

Where the function under test looks like this:

```
string FileExplorer::next_file_name() {
    char entry[255];
    if (fgets((char *)entry, 255, _sorted_entries_in_dir) == NULL)
        return string();
    _current_idx++;
    if (_current_idx == _line_offsets.size())
        _line_offsets.push_back(static_cast<unsigned>(char_traits<char>::length(entry)) + _line_offsets.back());
    return string(entry);
}
```

I'm using catch2 as the testing framework here, but I think hippomocks would work with Google's Testing framework as well (I recommend catch2, by the way, really easy to work with).

Comment: For anyone encountering this answer and getting hyped to find a very basic way of mocking free functions, don't even consider using this framework with clangd. If you don't set a -f-no-inline flag, it will flat out fail at the execution of any mocked function. And if you manage to run the mocked function after a long struggle, it will still fail at the end of each gtest case, as it tries to reset itself before destroying itself. Wasted many hours.

Comment: A correction, **Hippomocks** works decently with **clangd** (clang-r450784d1 for armeabi-v7a) when the line `add_compile_options(-O0 -fno-inline -fno-inline-functions -fno-lto -g -fno-optimize-sibling-calls)` is added, and all lines involving exception throwing are commented out. Make sure to have only one instance of `MockRepository`, keeping a global object of `MockRepository`, even when it is replaced at `TearDown()` with new instance, causes SIGSEGV. Likely because assigning new instance of `MockRepository` doesn't destroy the original object when the variable has global lifetime?

Answer (score 2):

Of course, the answer explaining the solution according to GTest/GMock's documentation couldn't be much more correct.

But I would like to add a temporary quick&dirty approach. It should be applicable to cases where you want to get legacy C/C++ code under test as quickly and as non-invasively as possible. (Just to proceed with fixes, refactoring and more proper testing as soon as possible after.)

So, to mock a free function `void foo(int)` appearing in some code to be tested, within the source file you just make the following adaptions:

```
#if TESTING
#define foo(param) // to nothing, so calls to that disappear
#endif

// ... code that calls foo stays untouched and could be tested
```

The macro `TESTING`, indicating that the code runs under test, doesn't come with GTest/GMock - you need to add it to test targets by yourself.

The possibilities are rather limited, but you might also be able to construct something useful for return types as `A*` in the question's example.

Unfortunately, also this isn't a solution without changing the code.
If that is really necessary, you could Google for 'link seams'. But my guess is that this could be quite a hassle in practice. And it even might not be possible at all in many/most cases?!

Answer (score 1):

If your free function is in the form of an `std::function` object, you can mock it using [`MockFunction`](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/d9c55a48eddbc92434454ac2b28771870750e616/googlemock/docs/cook_book.md#mock-stdfunction-mockfunction).  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57691219/3177701)

Answer (score 0):

What has worked for me is

- to define `A* foo()` in a separate source file `foo.cpp` in the main project,
- *not* to include `foo.cpp` in the test project,
- include a different source file `mock-foo.cpp` in the test project that provides the mock implementation of `A* foo()`.

For example, pseudocode for the main project file (e.g. `.vcxproj` or `CMakeLists.txt`):

```
include src/foo.hpp # declare A* foo()
include src/foo.cpp # define A* foo()
```

and the test project file:

```
include src/foo.hpp
include test/mock-foo.cpp # define mocked A* foo()
```

Simple and sweet, but may or may not work in your case.

Comment: In this scenario, how do you check from you Gtest that the mock function is called or manipulate its behavior for a specific test?