# Is there any way to mock the return value of a called function?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, mocking, code-coverage, googlemock

```
class A
{
    public:
        int ret1();
};
int ret()
{
    printf("Returning 5\n");
    return 5;
}

int A::ret1()
{
    int iRet = 10;
    printf("Inside ret1\n");
    iRet = ret();
    if (iRet == 5)
    {
        printf("Original ret is called\n");
    }
    else if (iRet == 100)
    {
        printf("This is mocked function call\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Opps! This should not happen\n");
    }
    return iRet;
}
```

In the above `ret1` function I would like to mock the return value of `ret` function's. Normally `ret` returns `5` but after mocking lets say `ret` will return 100 so `ret1` will print `"This is mocked function call"`.

Is there any tool to do the above situation. So as far I know cmocka can cover the above situation for C language but for C++ is there any tool available?

In the link [Mocking free function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28392277/mocking-free-function) doesn't look like answering my question.

Comment: https://github.com/google/googletest include googlemock for creating mock objects.

Comment: I tried my best but couldn't find it. Can you please let me know which section or with an example mock code?

Comment: @Jarod42 The above mentioned link doesn't look like it is alike. Can you please let me know how to mock the return value of `ret` while `ret1` is called? So the output would print "This is mocked function call"

Comment: Something like [this](https://ideone.com/SHewh8)

Comment: @Jarod42: I appreciate your effort. But this is not the change I am looking for. My base code which I mentioned in the question can not be changed. So with the help of mocking of `ret` function's return value I would like to have 100% line coverage of `ret1` function.