# How to mock independent function in gmock C++?

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

I am using gtest/gmock framework to write unit tests. Following is my sample code.

In common.h,

```
void PreInit() {
  cout<<"Doing Pre-initialization."<<endl; 
}
```

In test.cpp,

```
 #include <common.h>
    class SampleComponent {
    public:
        void Init() {
           PreInit();
           // Do Initialization
        }
    }
```

So far, I have been mocking classes. Any idea how to mock independent functions called by member functions of class?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't, you need to rethink your design to make it possible to inject a different function

Comment: I think there should be some way to mock C-style non-class function.. I could see few articles but wanted full example..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mocking free function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28392277/mocking-free-function)