# Google test for a function from a translation unit file

Tags: c++, unit-testing, visual-c++, googletest

I have a function defined in a translation unit file (.cpp) something like:

```
    void myFunction(int option)
    {
        if (option == 0)
        {
            Meth1("arg1");
        }
        else
        {
            if (option == 1)
            {
                Meth1("arg2");
            }
            else
            {
                Meth2("arg3");
            }
        }
    }
```

This function has its definition in a header file but is not part of a class or struct it is just implemented in the cpp file as above. No refactoring is allowed.

Now I need to write a unit test for it to check which method is called  based on the option argument. Something like in test I have

```
myFunction(0);

now I am testing that the Meth1 is called and its parameter has the "arg1" value.
```

Is it possible to write such a test ?

Comment: `Meth1(...)` has no return value, so I assume it must have a side-effect you can test?

Comment: Yes, this is possible with using macros or, if Math2 is in a library, with using a mock library.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mocking free function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28392277/mocking-free-function)

Comment: @S.M. OP mentions that the free function is defined in a non-editable source file, so mocking is probably not an option here.

Comment: @Mansoor Did I mention editing the source file?

Comment: @S.M. how else would you implement your mocked free function?

Comment: @Mansoor Meth1 and Meth2 are having no return values (are void).

Comment: @S.M. unfortunately this code can not be edit, and all those are free functions, which only got their declarations inside some headers.  Will check the answer from the question you suggested, but at a first look I do not think that will have something to mock Thank you !

Comment: @Mansoor Do you see the difference between mock library and mock free function? The duplicated question contains all possibilities, choose any, but do not say I offered modifying free functions.