# How to test a program using SDL without a graphical interface?

Tags: c++, sdl, googletest

I made a C++ program that uses SDL for display and sound. I am implementing gtest to test the graphical functions, for example to draw a pixel :

```cpp
void Interface::draw_pixel(unsigned short x, unsigned short y, bool on) {
  if (on) {
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 255, 255, SDL_ALPHA_OPAQUE);
  } else {
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, SDL_ALPHA_OPAQUE);
  }
  SDL_Rect rect = {normalize_x(x), normalize_y(y), SIZE_MULTIPLIER_, SIZE_MULTIPLIER_};
  SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &rect);
}
```

And to check if this pixel is indeed drawn :

```cpp
bool Interface::is_pixel_on(int x, int y) {
  p_ = (uint8_t *) SDL_GetWindowSurface(window)->pixels + normalize_y(y) * SDL_GetWindowSurface(window)->pitch +
       normalize_x(x) * bpp_;
  SDL_GetRGB(*(uint32_t *) p_, SDL_GetWindowSurface(window)->format, &rgb_.r, &rgb_.g, &rgb_.b);
  return rgb_.r != 0;
}
```

I would like to draw a pixel and check if it is drawn in C.I. tests. I have tried to create the SDL window with the `SDL_WINDOW_HIDDEN` flag but it doesn't draw and my test fail.

Do you have any idea or hints how it should be done?

Comment: Separate your logic between gui and calculation. Don't test if library draw the point. Test if your logic put the point to the right position and render.

Comment: You can do that with offscreen software renderer (don't create window but surface instead, and associate renderer with that surface). However SDL_GetWindowSurface is just wrong here even if window is present.

Comment: Question is what are you trying to test? Testing UI using unit test (gtest) is usually hard or pointless.

Comment: I am making a CHIP8 interpreter, and I want to check that one instruction will indeed print the sprite on the display.
Should I have a separated screen memory that SDL would jsut display ? And I can test the value of pixel directly from that memory? Because currently my display memory is within SDL.

Comment: My suggestion is still relevant and I found a source might be [helping](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28392341/4123703).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, unit tests don't test gui but logics.

Have a layer of abstraction between library and your logic.

Eg:

```
namespace mygui
{
    RenderFillRect(MyRenderer renderer, MyRect* rect);
};

void Interface::draw_pixel(unsigned short x, unsigned short y, bool on) {
  if (on) {
    MySetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 255, 255, SDL_ALPHA_OPAQUE);
  } else {
    MySetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, SDL_ALPHA_OPAQUE);
  }
  MyRect rect = {normalize_x(x), normalize_y(y), SIZE_MULTIPLIER_, SIZE_MULTIPLIER_};
  MyRenderFillRect(renderer, &rect);
}
```

Mock `mygui::RenderFillRect` and check if it's called with correct arguments after calling `Interface::draw_pixel`.

---

After your elaborated in comment about testing for CHIP8 interpreter, my suggestion is still relevant.

I'll suggest you to mock SDL function calls by using the instruction [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28392341/4123703).

Another way is mocking `Interface::draw_pixel()` to make sure one instruction is writing to the correct position.

I'm not sure when do you need to test SDL library. The only scenario I came up with is that it might breaks when you upgrade the library version. However most of time it doesn't get upgraded frequently.