# How to mock system call in C++ Unit Testing during runtime using GoogleMock?

Tags: c++, c, unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

I have a module written in C. In which I have API defined as follow.

```
int ReadData(void* data, int data_size, char* filename, int offset)
```

When performing unit test in order to cover full coverage I need to hit at error condition for fseek and fread system call.
Can somebody explain me How can I override fseek/fread during particular test case so instead of system call it will call mock fseek/fread for that test case ?

```
ReadAPI.c
```

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int readdata(void* data,int size, int offset, char* filename)
{
    if(data == NULL || size == 0 || filename == NULL)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    FILE* fp = fopen(filename,"rb");
    if(fp == NULL)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    if(fseek(fp,offset,SEEK_SET) != 0)
    {
        fclose(fp);
        return -1;
    }

    fread(data,size,1,fp);

    if(ferror(fp))
    {
        fclose(fp);
        return -1;
    }   
    fclose(fp);
    return 1;
}
```

```
readapi.h
```

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int readdata(void* data,int size, int offset, char* filename)
```

```
Test.cpp
```

```
#include<gtest/gtest.h>
#include"readapi.h"


TEST(test, Test1fseek)
{
    // When fseek called in readdata API call mock fseek to hit fseek fail  
    // fseek(){return -1;}
    char data[10] = {0};
    int status = readdata(data,sizeof(data),0,"test.txt");
    EXPECT_EQ(status, -1);  
}

TEST(test, Test2fread)
{
    //When fread called in readdata API call mock fread to hit read fail  
    // fread(){return -1;}
    char data[10] = {0};
    int status = readdata(data,sizeof(data),0,"test.txt");
    EXPECT_EQ(status, -1);  
}

int main()
{
    return RUN_ALL_TEST();
}
```

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: I am using g++ compiler this Is on linux . @TedLyngmo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can refer to [mocking-free-functions](http://google.github.io/googletest/gmock_cook_book.html#mocking-free-functions) in Gmock's documentation.

Unfortunately, using the recommended method means you will have to change your code, which may not work if your code need to strictly be a `C` code.

However, if you are willing to accept this, based on the documentation, you will have to create a wrapper around all the system functions that you are using and then mock that wrapper.

Also, don't forget that you will have to add `EXPECT_CALL` or `ON_CALL` for all functions that are expected to be called and return a non-default (i.e. 0) value. For example, in your first test, you should also provide `EXPECT_CALL` or `ON_CALL` for `fopen`.

Here is an example implementation:

```
// System wrapper interface class.
class MySystemWrapperInterface {
 public:
  virtual FILE* fopen(const char* filename, const char* mode) = 0;
  virtual int fseek(FILE* stream, long int offset, int whence) = 0;
  virtual size_t fread(void* ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE* stream) = 0;
  virtual int ferror(FILE* stream) = 0;
  virtual int fclose(FILE* stream) = 0;
};

// System wrapper actual class used in production code.
class MySystemWrapperClass : public MySystemWrapperInterface {
 public:
  FILE* fopen(const char* filename, const char* mode) {
    return ::fopen(filename, mode);
  }
  int fseek(FILE* stream, long int offset, int whence) {
    return ::fseek(stream, offset, whence);
  }
  size_t fread(void* ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE* stream) {
    return ::fread(ptr, size, nmemb, stream);
  }
  int ferror(FILE* stream) { return ::ferror(stream); }
  int fclose(FILE* stream) { return ::fclose(stream); }
};

// Mocked System wrapper used for testint.
class MySystemWrapperMockClass : public MySystemWrapperInterface {
 public:
  MOCK_METHOD(FILE*, fopen, (const char*, const char*), (override));
  MOCK_METHOD(int, fseek, (FILE*, long int, int), (override));
  MOCK_METHOD(size_t, fread, (void*, size_t, size_t, FILE*), (override));
  MOCK_METHOD(int, ferror, (FILE*), (override));
  MOCK_METHOD(int, fclose, (FILE*), (override));
};

// Wrapper class for your own readdata function.
class MyClass {
  // The system wrapper passed by dependency injection through constructor.
  MySystemWrapperInterface* system_wrapper_;

 public:
  // Initialize the system wrapper in constructor.
  MyClass(MySystemWrapperInterface* system_wrapper)
      : system_wrapper_(system_wrapper) {}

  int readdata(void* data, int size, int offset, char* filename) {
    if (data == NULL || size == 0 || filename == NULL) {
      return -1;
    }

    FILE* fp = system_wrapper_->fopen(filename, "rb");
    if (fp == NULL) {
      return -1;
    }

    if (system_wrapper_->fseek(fp, offset, SEEK_SET) != 0) {
      system_wrapper_->fclose(fp);
      return -1;
    }

    system_wrapper_->fread(data, size, 1, fp);

    if (system_wrapper_->ferror(fp)) {
      system_wrapper_->fclose(fp);
      return -1;
    }
    system_wrapper_->fclose(fp);
    return 1;
  }
};

TEST(test, Test1fseek) {
  // Create the mock object and inject it into your class.
  MySystemWrapperMockClass mock_system_wrapper;
  MyClass my_object(&mock_system_wrapper);

  // When fseek called in readdata API call mock fseek to hit fseek fail
  // fseek(){return -1;}

  // IMPORTANT: Don't forget to add EXPECT_CALL or ON_CALL for all functions
  // that are expected to be called.
  EXPECT_CALL(mock_system_wrapper, fopen)
      .Times(1)
      .WillOnce(Return(reinterpret_cast<FILE*>(0x1)));

  EXPECT_CALL(mock_system_wrapper, fseek).Times(1).WillOnce(Return(1));
  EXPECT_CALL(mock_system_wrapper, fclose).Times(1).WillOnce(Return(1));

  char data[10] = {0};
  int status = my_object.readdata(data, sizeof(data), 0, "test.txt");
  EXPECT_EQ(status, -1);
}

TEST(test, Test2fread) {
  // Create the mock object and inject it into your class.
  MySystemWrapperMockClass mock_system_wrapper;
  MyClass my_object(&mock_system_wrapper);

  // When fread called in readdata API call mock fread to hit read fail
  // fread(){return -1;}
  // IMPORTANT: Don't forget to add EXPECT_CALL or ON_CALL for all functions
  // that are expected to be called.
  EXPECT_CALL(mock_system_wrapper, fopen)
      .Times(1)
      .WillOnce(Return(reinterpret_cast<FILE*>(0x1)));
  EXPECT_CALL(mock_system_wrapper, fseek).Times(1).WillOnce(Return(0));
  EXPECT_CALL(mock_system_wrapper, fread).Times(1).WillOnce(Return(-1));
  EXPECT_CALL(mock_system_wrapper, ferror).Times(1).WillOnce(Return(-1));
  EXPECT_CALL(mock_system_wrapper, fclose).Times(1).WillOnce(Return(1));

  char data[10] = {0};
  int status = my_object.readdata(data, sizeof(data), 0, "test.txt");
  EXPECT_EQ(status, -1);
}
```

Live example: https://godbolt.org/z/qxf74fWGh

Comment: And how to call the real system library function in the production code?

Comment: @Ingo: By calling `MySystemWrapperClass::` methods.

Comment: OK, wrong question. I wanted to ask: how to call a function (real or mocked) in the production code? isn't it to use an instance of MyClass to get the injected version?

Answer (score 4):

If you are using `gcc`/`g++` or `clang`/`clang++` you can use the linker option `--wrap=symbol` to redirect calls to your own versions of these functions.

Your wrapper functions will have the name `__wrap_symbol` and the real functions will be named `__real_symbol`.

Example:

```c
int __wrap_fseek(FILE *stream, long offset, int whence) {
    printf("__wrap_fseek: %ld %d\n", offset, whence);
    return __real_fseek(stream, offset, whence);
}

size_t __wrap_fread(void *restrict ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb,
                    FILE *restrict stream)
{
    return __real_fread(ptr, size, nmemb, stream);
}
```

Compile with `g++ ... -Wl,--wrap=fseek,--wrap=fread`

Comment: Is there way I can do same using GoogleMock framework to override system call with mock one as it seems GoggleMock is used for that but I am not getting how to do that

Comment: @raj123 I don't know much about googletest but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28392277/mocking-free-function) seems to say that it's possible.

Comment: thanks this one also something new I learnt

Comment: @raj123 You're welcome!